# Migration of data stored in RavenDB

Tags: .net, ravendb

I have entities stored in RavenDB (build #888). I need to change theirs IDs, because of database migration, connected with newer version of the application.

I've written sample function I'm using:

```
public bool Migrate()
{
    using (var session = _store.OpenSession())
    {
        var users = session.Query<User>().ToList();
        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            user.Id = user.Email;
        }
        session.SaveChanges();
     }
}
```

Execution of this code results in an exception:

```
Status: System.InvalidOperationException: Entity App.Models.Entities.User had document key 'mydomain-mylogin' but now has document key property 'mylogin@yahoo.com'.
You cannot change the document key property of a entity loaded into the session
   at Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.CreatePutEntityCommand(Object entity, DocumentMetadata documentMetadata)
   at Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.PrepareForEntitiesPuts(SaveChangesData result)
   at Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.PrepareForSaveChanges()
   at Raven.Client.Document.DocumentSession.SaveChanges()
```

How can it be done ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My current solution is copying current entities to temporary ones, changing desired properties, storing such new entities in database, and finally removing old ones:

```
using (var session = _store.OpenSession())
{
    var users = session.Query<User>().ToList();
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        var newuser = new User
                          {
                              Id = user.Email,
                              DisplayName = user.DisplayName
                          };

        session.Store(newuser);
        session.Delete(user);
    }
    session.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: The Id field is a fundamental part of the document as it's the key used for looking it up. So that's why you're prevented from changing it.

Comment: Creating a new doc and then deleting the old one is the easiest way to do this.

Comment: Thanks, it's just like I've done that a few minutes ago. Regards.